Is there a way to access a Sharepoint file that requires credentials through a live server using Javascript?
Context: I have a web application (Javascript + No Library - Pure JS) that uses Highcharts JS to generate data visualisation. Currently the visualisation is built with data from a local .JSON file.
Goal: I want to read the .JSON file from a Sharepoint folder instead.
Issue / What I have done:: I launched a development local Server with live reload feature and I replaced the filepath of my local JSON file to the Sharepoint link.
However, I got the following error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at sharepoint_link (redirected from
'second_link') from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by
CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
requested resource.

Question: Is there a way for me to read the file from my application? If so, how can I do it?

You are looking for this SDK or the REST API
